# 2005 Chevy Aveo doesn't acclerate over 60 mph

Tags: chevrolet, acceleration, aveo

This problem just begin yesterday. It's doesn't go past 60 mph and I don't know what's wrong. Can someone please answer this please?

Comment: Please give us more info. Are there any CELs? How is it running differently? Is it stick or auto? Does it sound like the engine will go faster, but isn't gettint it there? Any information will help!

Comment: The CEL is the engine light, it's a stick,it does sound loud. No, the engine doesn't seem like it'll go faster but won't go. We just got the car fixed last week then the hose on the intake fell apart and we bought a new one and put it on thinking that it would fix the problem. I hope I gave you more than enough information. And thank you for replying

Comment: Go somewhere and have the codes read. I don't know where you are, but here in the States, most nationally chained parts stores (AutoZone, Advance Auto, Checkers, etc.) will read your codes for free. Write the codes down and let us know what they are ... should help tremendously. Also, let us know what year your Aveo is and what engine is in it (it may only have one available, but please let us know anyway).

Comment: I live in Pa. The year of the car is 2005 w/ hatchback. The engine is 1.6.

Comment: You got it fixed last week - what was wrong with it before, and what work was done on it? That could be related.

Comment: By the way, it is better to edit your question to add these details - comments are not intended to be permanent.